# Regex PHP , find words in specific location

Tags: php, regex

Hi everyone here is the problem :

I got a classic address ex : `25 Park Street 15000 **My city**`.

I'm looking for a regex to find only the city in this address.

I have already worked on it and i found something good :`[^ ]*$`

The problem is that this regex only take the last word of my string and my cities may have more words ex : `**New York**`.

I understand that i have to find all characters ***after*** the postal code.

Keep searching , but maybe you can help me !

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming digits cannot appear in city names, you can use a `\d\s*(\D+)$` regex to match the last digit with optional whitespace and then match and capture all other characters up to the end of string.

```
\d\s*(\D+)$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kE3sJ0/1)

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/dZ5mTF):

```
$str = "25 Park Street 15000 My city"; 
preg_match('/\d\s*(\D+)$/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

An alternative (a bit more complex) is to try to find a common pattern for city names. Assuming it may contain spaces, hyphens and single apostrophes, you could try an [alternative regex](https://regex101.com/r/kE3sJ0/2):

```
'/[\p{L}\p{M}]+(?:[- \'][\p{L}\p{M}]+)*$/u'
```

Here, `\p{L}` matches any Unicode letter, `\p{M}` diacritical marks, `[- ']` will match a hyphen or a space or a single apostrophe.

```
preg_match('/[\p{L}\p{M}]+(?:[- \'][\p{L}\p{M}]+)*$/u', $str, $matches);
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/3fZblh)

Comment: It's really close but has you can see in your regex demo , the last number of postal is include in the result of the regex. That's the only problem of your work, but i will try to fix this, if you got an idea to fix this too i will be really enjoyed .

Comment: @VERYNET: Please check the code demo, the number is in the match, but it is *not inside the first capture group* - that is what you need to use. You do not need to use a look-behind, it will slow down regex performance. Using capture groups here is a logical solution here.

Comment: It's ok i saw the problem i had with the first regex and it perfectly works in my code . By the way, the second is really clean and works perfectly too . Thanks for your help and advices.

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*\b\d+\b\s*\K|[\w\s]*$
```

You can use this directly.See demo.`\K` will disregard the non useful stuff.

https://regex101.com/r/kE3sJ0/3